# NCEP.interp fails 'Error in if (format(dt.f, "%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

Tags: datetime, rstudio

I wonder if anyone can advise,

I am trying to extract precipitation rate to particular samples from the RNCEP database using the package RNCEP and function NCEP.interp.

First, I am importing a worksheet from an .xlsx with one column containing a Sample_Date in the format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.

Second, I use NCEP.interp which seems to run great to 18% when it gives the following error and stops:

```
Error in if (format(dt.f, "%m-%d %H:%M:%S") > "12-31 17:59:59") { : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

There are also a series of warnings referring to download length, for example:

```
50: In download.file(paste("http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/thredds/dodsC/Datasets/ncep.reanalysis",  ... : downloaded length 522 != reported length 200
```

But, I don't think the warnings are an issue (including for completeness). My complete code is:

```
install.packages("RNCEP", dependencies =TRUE)
library(RNCEP)

SampPre6 <- read.xlsx("C:....Rainfall.xlsx",
                sheetName = "1")
SampPre6$Sample_Date <- strptime(as.character(SampPre6$Sample_Date), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
format(SampPre6$Sample_Date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

PratePre6 <- NCEP.interp(variable='prate.sfc', level='gaussian', 
                   lat=SampPre6$Latitude,lon=SampPre6$Longitude,
                   dt=SampPre6$Sample_Date,reanalysis2=TRUE, 
                   keep.unpacking.info = TRUE)
```

An example of the data is:

```
   Sample_ID         Sample_Date Latitude Longitude
1        151 2013-03-15 23:29:59 31.39725  121.5068
2        177 2013-04-13 00:14:59 31.39695  121.5067
3        500 2013-04-13 06:59:59 23.26420  113.5147
4        501 2013-04-13 08:15:00 23.26168  113.5214
5        502 2013-04-13 09:00:00 23.27464  113.5529
6        247 2013-04-26 19:44:59 22.45018  114.1511
7        246 2013-04-26 21:14:59 22.45174  114.1346
8        245 2013-04-26 22:30:00 22.43341  114.1168
9        300 2013-05-18 00:59:59 31.39733  121.5067
10       584 2013-06-04 01:15:00 23.18805  113.4910
```

In summary, can anyone shed any light on the error message that causes the process to stop?

Thanks in advance,
Ian

Answer (score 1):

The dt parameter should be of the type "character" as specified in the help files ?NCEP.interp

Before running NCEP.interp(), try including the following...

SampPre6$Sample_Date <- format(SampPre6$Sample_Date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")